# Webkit Animation not working in index.html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a loading splash screen in angular while everything is loading in the background.

I have webkit animation on a moving ellipses however it isn't working in the index.html. The application is loading message shows but the animation doesn't work. Does anyone know why the animation wouldn't work if I have the style tags declared?

```
<app-root>
      <style type="text/css">
          #pre-bootstrap {
              background-color: #262626;
              bottom: 0px;
              left: 0px;
              position: fixed;
              right: 0px;
              top: 0px;
              z-index: 999999;
          }

          #pre-bootstrap div.messaging {
              color: #FFFFFF;
              font-family: monospace;
              left: 0px;
              margin-top: -37px;
              position: absolute;
              right: 0px;
              text-align: center;
              top: 50%;
          }

          #pre-bootstrap h1 {
              font-size: 22px;
              line-height: 35px;
              margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
          }

          #pre-bootstrap p {
              font-size: 18px;
              line-height: 14px;
              margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
          }

          #pre-bootstrap span.one {
                      opacity: 0;
                      -webkit-animation: dot 1.3s infinite;
                      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.0s;
                      animation: dot 1.3s infinite;
                      animation-delay: 0.0s;
                  }

          #pre-bootstrap span.two {
              opacity: 0;
              -webkit-animation: dot 1.3s infinite;
              -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
              animation: dot 1.3s infinite;
              animation-delay: 0.2s;
          }

          #pre-bootstrap span.three {
              opacity: 0;
              -webkit-animation: dot 1.3s infinite;
              -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
              animation: dot 1.3s infinite;
              animation-delay: 0.3s;
          }
    </style>

    <div id="pre-bootstrap">
      <div class="messaging">  
          <h1>         
              Application is Loading <span class="one">.</span><span class="two">.</span><span class="three">.</span>  
          </h1>            
        </div>
     </div> 
</app-root>
```

Comment: Did you actually define the `dot` animation keyframes anywhere? I don't see them in your style tags

Comment: Yes I have them as class="two" which matches with span.two

Comment: I'm talking about the `@keyframes` css rule. If you do have those could you add them to your question then please? It's hard to help without them. (if you don't have those then that is definitely the issue)

Comment: I dont have those. Where should they go?

Comment: Inside your style element (or in a separate CSS file). Please read about how to use CSS animations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **keyframes** for css animation like this:

```
@keyframes dot{
  from { transform:rotate(0deg)}
  to {transform:rotate(360deg)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the `@keyframes` rule.

Check out this link for more info about that CSS rule: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes